# Python - Create AWS Signature with temporary security credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-s3

I have read the AWS documentation but I couldn't find an example of using Temporary Security Credentials to authenticate to AWS with Python.

I would like an example of using a temporary security credentials provided by the AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) to sign a request.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can use STS to get temporary credential. The two most common ones would be:

- [get_session_token](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token) - used to get temp credentials for existing IAM user or account
- [assume_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) - used to get credentials when assuming [iam role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

In both cases the call to these function will give you temp credentials, e.g.:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "AddsdfsdfsdxxxxxxKJ",
        "SecretAccessKey": "TEdsfsdfSfdsfsdfsdfsdclkb/",
        "SessionToken": "FwoGZXIvYXdzEFkaDGgIUSvDdfgsdfgsdfgsMaVYgsSxO8OqRfjHc4se90WbaspOwCtdgZNgeasdfasdfasdf5wrtChz2QCTnR643exObm/zOJzXe9TUkcdODajHtxcgR8r+unzMo+7WxgQYyKGN9kfbCqv3kywk0EvOBCapusYo81fpv8S7j4JQxEwOGC9JZQL6umJ8=",
        "Expiration": "2021-02-17T11:53:31Z"
    }
}
```

Having these credentials, you create **new** boto3 [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session), e.g.:

```
  new_session = boto3.session.Session(<temp credentails>)
```

The `new_session` will allow you to make new boto3 `client` or `resource`, e.g.:

```
 ec2 = new_session.client('ec2')
 s3r = new_session.resource('s3')
```

And then you can use these new clients/resource as you would normally use them.

Comment: Thank you !I don't want to use the AWS SDKs to handle the signature calculation process for me, I want to manually complete the signing process.

Comment: @EmmaGrove There is no difference is creating the signature. If you know how to do it using regular credentials, it will be same with temp credentials.

Comment: @EmmaGrove You only need to account for the token, as explained in the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html). Its not used in the signature creation itself, but must be added as an extra header.

Comment: I did add it in the header but I get signature doesn't match. And if I use postman with the same creds it works

Comment: @EmmaGrove I would suggest making new question, with the code that you use, exact error details. Sadly, your current question does not have any details which would allow to reproduce the issue and  pin-point why your code does not work.

Comment: @EmmaGrove Also you can check existing source code, such as [this](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) and compare with yours.

Comment: I'm on phone now. I used the first example ~Using GET with an authorization header (Python)~ and I simply added X-Amz-Security-Token in the header. Tomorrow I'm gonna edit the question with more details

Comment: @EmmaGrove How did it go?